# Error message when use Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pysam

I need to convert a very huge .bam file to .bed file, although I found a solution by using bedops's bam2bed parallel, that parallel support SEG and gnuParallel, the two clusters I can access only support slurm and torque schedulers, and I do not know much about tcsh, I can even not modify the script to meet the require of slurm and torque.

Due to I know a little about Python, I plan to use Python's multiprocessing module to do this, however, the following code raise a weird message:

***"Python quit unexpectedly while using the calignmentfile.so plug-in"***

```
# The code here is just a test code, ignore its real meaning.
import multiprocessing as mp
import pysam

def work(read):
    return read.query
    # return read.split()[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cpu = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(cpu)

    sam = pysam.AlignmentFile('foo.bam', 'rb')
    read = sam.fetch(until_eof=True)

    # f = open('foo.text', 'rb')
    # results = pool.map(work, f, cpu)

    results = pool.map(work, read, cpu)
    print(results)
```

Does this message mean the reads from pysam.AlignmentFile() does not support parallelism, or Python doesn't support this kind of parallel? I use a regular text file test this piece of code, it works well (e.g. the code was commented).

Answer (score 0):

`pysam` indeed has some problems with concurrency. If you see the [source code for `fetch`](https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam/blob/244a416863aa13c1e9d5abfb3900e70e5d23adb1/pysam/calignmentfile.pyx#L792) you'll see there's a [problem with concurrency and iterating](https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam/blob/244a416863aa13c1e9d5abfb3900e70e5d23adb1/pysam/calignmentfile.pyx#L1539) it's return types